# Presenting a ViewController from the AppDelegate, it shows up but the navbar is not active and I can not transition to any other view from there

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have a function that is listening for a user location change and based on some conditions I want to open up a view controller on the storyboard. This view controller is usually opened up from a tableviewconroller when clicked on a cell. what I want is to transition to this view controller from the appdelegate. I have been trying many combinations of code from sort of similar post on this website, but none of them loaded the page properly so I can use the navigation after that. This is the closest I have got to:

```
 if(site != nil){

        if (currentExhibitionSiteId != site?.ID) {

            currentExhibitionSiteId = (site?.ID)!


            let storyboard  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as!DetailViewController
            detailViewController.site = site

            let locTable = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sitesTable") as! LocationsTableViewController



            let frontNav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: detailViewController)

            let rearNav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: locTable)

            let mainRoot = SWRevealViewController.init(rearViewController: rearNav, frontViewController: frontNav)

            self.window?.rootViewController = mainRoot
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


        }
    }
```

[this is the how it stays in the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGQfl.png)

Comment: This code looks like your replacing the current root view controller.  That won't transition from the old one to the new one, that will just replace it.  Can you clarify what you want to see in a transition?  Maybe you want a modal over the root?  Or a push from the root?  Or something custom?

Comment: I did not mean to replace the current root view controller, I am just new in that adventure of creating iOS apps. What is my purpose here: I have a bunch of sites and their coordinates. I am checking user's location and if the user is close to any of the locations I want the app to go to that detail view so they see info about that site. I need that to happen only within the app from any view.

Comment: Also I am using **SWRevealViewController** for my menu.

Comment: what you probably want to do then is to make sure your initial rootviewcontroller is a navigation controller and then push a new view controller onto the existing navigationController.  There are several ways to do that.  Let me know if you need help and I'll post and answer

Comment: Thank you! It would be very nice to see what your suggestion is! Much appreciated! Thank you bolnad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to overwrite the existing rootViewController.  You could try re-architecting your structure a little bit and making the original rootViewController a `UINavigationController`.  Then you can just add a `detailViewController` to that via a show call.

In your AppDelegate on initial setup it might look something like this....

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  
    if let window = self.window {

         if let window = self.window {

        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        navController =  window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    }
    return true
}
```

You would also store a reference to your main UINavigationController as a property.  `var navController: UINavigationController?`  Or you could cast it each time from the `window.rootViewController`.

Your Main Storyboard would then consist of a UINavigationController, with a UITableViewController connected to it, and then your DetailViewController that you want to show when someone clicks on a cell.  I made a basic storyboard for that and it would look like this.[image: StoryboardImage]

Keep in mind that you would need to select isInitialViewController on the UINavigationController property inspector to make this work.[image: InitialViewControllerCheckbox]

When you want to trigger a view to be moved on top of the existing view, i.e. in your method onLocationChanged, you can then reference that navController property to add a view

```
 func onLocationChanged(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let site: ExhibitionSite? = self.exhibitionSiteRepository.findClosestSite(location)


    if(site != nil){

        if (currentExhibitionSiteId != site?.ID) {
             currentExhibitionSiteId = (site?.ID)!
             let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
             let detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
            detailViewController!.site = site

            navController?.showViewController(detailViewController, sender: self)
        }

 }
```

Here you are loading the Main Storyboard and requesting the `DetailViewController` by its identifier.  Make sure that the DetailViewController has an identifier filled out so you can access it otherwise it will crash.

If you don't want it to push onto the screen like a navigationController animation then you can change that call to `.presentViewController(detailViewController, animated: false, completion:nil)` and then it will pop a full modal over your existing view.

Hope this helps and I'm not sure how you've utilized this SWRevealMenuController as to how it affects your Storyboard.  From what I know of SWRevealMenuController it takes over a little of your hierarchy, so maybe it makes sense to move all the location changed stuff into the top view controller under the UINavigationController.  It doesn't look like there is any reason the locationChanged stuff NEEDs to be on the AppDelegate. If you run into issues, i can take a closer look.

Comment: hello bolnad, sorry I was away for some time. I am still struggling with this issue. I have changed the code to be as it is above in the edited question. I have the SWRevealViewController as my root and changes to the other views may damage the structure of the app, so I rather try and fix it as it is. When changed to the above code, my detail view loads but the navigation on the top is still not working. I have included a screenshot of storyboard. Many thanks.

Comment: @stan maybe it's easier to share your code? Would u feel comfortable putting it somewhere so I can the implementation you have?

Comment: What exactly you need and where do I send it to you? In short explanation, I have locations on the map with annotations! When you tap on a location this opens the details view about the location! I also have a tableview with all the locations, from which you can also navigate to the details page! The menu for the app and the navigation is handled by the SWRevealViewController and each section from the menu has its own navigation controller! See the image I have put above! My goal is to open up the details page when the user is close to location! I am handling that in the appdelegate

Comment: @stan just zip it up and put it on Dropbox is something, I'm missing something stupid I'm sure and it's easier for me to work with existing layout than to build something new from scratch and not mimic your setup

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this approach I would make a manual segue and call ViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier(...). This would let you do a show segue and preserve the navigation bar on the `UINavigationController` object.

Comment: perform segue is not triggering from the appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

Embed `DetailViewController`in `UINavigationController`. Customize your `NavigationBar` from `Story Board`. Give a `StoryboardID` to this navigation controller. Let it be `MyNavVC`. Then modify your code to

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyNavVC") as? UINavigationController

    (navController.rootViewController as! DetailViewController)!.site = site
    self.window!.rootViewController = navController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: this looks good but the line : **(navController.rootViewController as! DetailViewController)!.site = site** is not accepted it gives error - Value of 'UINavigationController?' has no member 'rootViewController'